# How to restore with Duplicty if Temp space has 0 available?

Tags: backup, configuration, backup-restoration, duplicity, options

Normally this command works properly for restoring:

duplicity restore -t7D --file-to-restore folder/to_restore file:///where/is/the_backup/ /where_to_restore --no-encrypt
But today I am having this error:

Temp space has 0 available, where_to_restore needs approx 34078720.

Following the duplicity FAQs:

http://duplicity.nongnu.org/FAQ.html#tmp_space

I have added TMPDIR="/usr/tmp" to the bash_profile and done source ~/.bash_proflle but did not work.

Also, tried adding --tempdir /usr/tmp/ to the duplicity command

duplicity restore -t7D --file-to-restore folder/to_restore file:///where/is/the_backup/ /where_to_restore --no-encrypt --tempdir /usr/tmp/

But did not work neither.

I am pretty sure it has an easy solution but I can't figure where to find the info.

edit1:
I am using duplicity 0.6.08b over debian:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.10
Codename:       squeeze

Comment: what's your duplicity version? try `export TMPDIR=/usr/tmp` 
before running `duplicity. ..ede/duply.net`

Comment: I am using duplicity 0.6.08b over debian: Distributor ID: Debian Description: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze) Release: 6.0.10 Codename: squeeze.

Comment: If I do printenv TMPDIR after export TMPDIR=/usr/tmp the output it's ok: /usr/tmp but the duplicity command still with the same error message Temp space has 0 available, backup needs approx 34078720.

Comment: After all the message was pretty clear. It seems that my duplicity script was doing extra copies and has consumed all the free space. After deleting those extra copies and deleting the content of /cache/duplicity/ everything was working right.